# Cosa significa "stravento" riferito alla pioggia?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto questa frase:

> Dalla finestra aperta, la dura pioggia estiva comincia a battere **a stravento**, ma lei non può muoversi per chiuderla.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "stravento", ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Ricercando su Google, però, ho visto alcune frasi con questo termine che si riferiscono anche alla pioggia. Per esempio:

> - Incominciò a piovere a scrosci gelidi, **di stravento**, e nella chiesa in rovina le fiamme si spensero in fretta. (Ken Follett, *I pilastri della terra*).
> - Pioveva che Dio la mandava. Il tempaccio, **stravento** e acquazzoni, continuava da ore, ma il Calatafimi non aveva voluto sentire ragioni: «No, che non si rimanda. Se piove vuol dire che non vanno in giro e stanno chiusi in osteria. Quando arriviamo, li troviamo già mezzi cotti e dargliele sarà più facile». (Sergio Banali, *Avanti popolo: le lotte e le speranze dei "lauradur" in un romanzo padano*).
> - Entro in casa, l'entrata è allagata, l'acqua è entrata da sotto la porta, come succede quando piove forte **di stravento**.
> - Piove forte, tra raffiche rabbiose; proprio mentre mi avvicino, lo **stravento** manda uno scroscio a sciacquare i vetri fuligginosi. (Guido Morselli, *Un dramma borghese*).

La mia domanda è: cosa significa "stravento" in queste frasi? In particolare, qual è il significato delle espressioni "a stravento" e "di stravento"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ho trovato riferimenti a *stravento* in glossari e dizionari dialettali, e anche in manuali sulla manutenzione delle case. La pioggia a stravento è una pioggia molto forte e intensa che, per via del vento, cade non verticalmente ma obliquamente, e per questo può entrare nelle case attraverso porte e finestre se queste non sono ben sigillate.

*A stravento* e *di stravento* sono equivalenti.

In generale, il prefisso *stra-* (latino *extra*) in italiano può servire ad aumentare l'intensità della parola. Es. È un premio strameritato = È un premio meritatissimo.

Comment: Se ho capito bene l'uso che se ne fa in alcuni esempi, la "pioggia a stravento" si può chiamare anche semplicemente "stravento". È così?

Comment: In rete ho trovato anche esempi di "neve a stravento", "grandine a stravento". Negli esempi che hai trovato, si capisce che "stravento" si riferisce alla pioggia per altre parole che trovi vicino: "acquazzoni" nel secondo esempio, "scroscio" e "sciacquare" nel quarto, rimandano all'acqua, quindi alla pioggia (le tre parole, in più, dicono una pioggia intensa).

Comment: @Charo: nel Veneto, in dialetto, lo *stravento* significa *controvento*, *folata di vento contrario*. Chi va in barca a vela chiama l'andatura "di bolina" come  "de stravento". È andare a vela contro il vento, non direttamente ma in modo obliquo. Pioggia di stravento è quella che qui chiamiamo la pioggia di traverso, obliqua. Quindi come vedi l'uso della parola assume significati un po' diversi a seconda del contesto. Non sono sicuro della sua presenza in altri dialetti ma credo che sia più comune in quelli del nord, se è cosi non è una cosa che un italiano proveniente dal sud userebbe.

Comment: Da un'ulteriore ricerca sembra che nelle Marche dicano "piove a vento" ed in Campania usino "piove acqua e vento". Chi proviene da quelle zone forse confermerà (o no)

Answer (score 0):

L'uso del suffisso di "stravento" riferito alla pioggia è molteplice, ogni zona ne ha una collocazione e utilizzo nel parlare o nel riferirsi.
Nel nord est ha assunto il significato di pioggia con raffiche di vento che spinge l'acqua in finestra protette da tettoie:
"è entrata l'acqua di stravento".
L'uso della parola "stravento" è da assumersi anche quando piove nelle vicinanze e il vento porta la pioggia anche se sopra "perpendicolarmente" non ci sono nuvole: piove con il sole, "piove di stravento"